# How to control dimensions(Width and Length) of an image within a BIP report specifically when generating an output in Excel format (oracle EBS R12)

Tags: excel, image, bi-publisher, oracle-ebs

I am currently trying to retrieve an image within a BIP report intended for Excel output. Regrettably, I am facing difficulty in managing the dimensions (width and height) of these images. Consequently, the images are being displayed as originally stored by the client without the intended adjustments

i I have successfully managed to retrieve an image from the file system, and while I am able to display it in a standardized size of my choosing (e.g. width="300px" height="160px") within a PDF using the following formatting
**# <fo:instream-foreign-object content-type="image/PNG" width="300px" height="160px"></fo:instream-foreign-object> **
**However, I am encountering difficulties replicating this control and formatting when attempting to display the image in an Excel output**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I WANT TO CONTROL IMAGE SIZE IN BIP REPORT WHILE TAKING OUTPUT IN EXCEL IN ORACLE EBS R12

Comment: It is quite challenging to use any BIP approach for dynamically resizing images, as BIP is not designed for this purpose. You could consider using a service such as a database function or a web service endpoint. This might help you out.
Or you can share more details on requirement, might be i can help you in this.